# hosting a Ionic project on a server and accessing with a webview on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, webview, ionic3

I tryed to upload my IONIC 3 test app to a server (all files in www folder) and load it on my Android device.

I would like to do an android app (using Android Studio) with a WebView component to load the address: http://www.smartbit.inf.br/add

If a load it using Chrome on my android device, it opens well. But on my WebView app it stay blank and do not opens.
What am I doing wrong?

```
package br.inf.smartbit.diamante;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.smartbit.inf.br/app");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.smartbit.inf.br")) {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity( intent );
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```